# HTML5 Canvas determine shapes from a sillouette

Tags: html, image, canvas, shapes

I'm trying to identity the center x and y of a circle drawn from an png image source in a canvas, is there a context 2d function that can do this?
Or is there a function that can trace a circle in a png file so that I can identify its coordinates for center x and y?

I just need the logic thanks

Comment: Depends on the circle, is it solid, outlined, are there several circles, are they exact circles, specific color, ...? too broad as the question stands now imo.

Comment: only one black circle inside a wide white space background its position and radius is random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native method to identify shapes on an html5 canvas.

Once the pixels are drawn any information about how they were drawn (circle, rectangle, etc) is forgotton.

**A method to find your circle**

Your circle must be differentiated from the rest of the image.

Is it a unique color? Is the rest of the image transparent?

At the point where you have a differentiation, you can use `getImageData` to fetch the red, blue, green & alpha information about every pixel on the canvas.

```
var pixelData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
```

This pixelData is one long array with each pixel's color data being in an element:

```
firstPixelRed=pixelData[0];
firstPixelGreen=pixelData[1];
firstPixelBlue=pixelData[2];
firstPixelAlpah=pixelData[3];
//
secondPixelRed=pixelData[4];
secondPixelGreen=pixelData[5];
secondPixelBlue=pixelData[6];
secondPixelAlpah=pixelData[7];
```

You can use this pixelData to identify all pixels which are inside your circle.

From these "inside circle" pixels, find their minimumX, minimumY, maximumX & maximumY coordinates.

These minimums & maximums will give you the bounding box of the circle.

```
topleft    = [minumumX,minumimY]
topright   = [maximumX,minimumY]
bottomright= [maximumX,maximumY]
bottomleft = [minumumX,maximumY]
```

The radius of the circle is:

```
var radius = (maximumX - minimumX) /2;
```

So the center point of the circle is:

```
var centerX = minimumX + radius;
var centerY = minimumY + radius;
```

And you've got your circle with center point [centerX,centerY] with radius!